# Cordova Android local video playback used to work; now doesn't

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video

I have a Cordova application which downloads a video file to local storage and then plays it using a HTML `<video>` tag. This worked fine on iOS and Android up on Cordova version 3.7.1. I recently updated Cordova to the latest version (6.3.1) and now the video doesn't play on Android. iOS is working fine.

The video file is saved to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.my.package/foobar.mp4`; using ADB, I can see the file is being correctly saved (using `FileTransfer`) to that location. File size is correct, and permissions are user and group readable.

The video doesn't seem to load at all; `v.src` is empty, and `v.duration` is `NaN`, and `v.networkState` is 3 (`NETWORK_NO_SOURCE`)

The video element is

```
<video id="video" playsinline="1" webkit-plays-inline="1" poster preload="metadata">
    <source id="source" type="video/mp4" 
      src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.my.package/foobar.mp4">
</video>
```

I haven't changed the HTML or the Javascript since upgrading Cordova to 6.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

(Previous wrong answer removed.)

I think the problem was actually the Crosswalk plugin. Adding or removing the plugin doesn't take effect until you remove the platform and add it again, so I didn't suspect that.

Specifically, I had turned on the Crosswork option `--enable-unified-media-pipeline` to try to help me with a different issue (ability to set the video playback speed). Removing that option makes it work again. This is counter-intuitive because you're often recommended to turn that option on to fix video issues.